# How to keep default behavior when extending FloationActionButton?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I created my own FloatingActionButton. It extends from the original class.

I want to reproduce the same behavior of this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JLVL.gif)

But when I extend it, I lose the default animation behavior. There is a way to keep it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using @CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(FloatingActionButton.Behavior.class) does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your class with `@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(FloatingActionButton.Behavior.class)`.

The [`@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior.html) annotation defines a View's default CoordinatorLayout behavior to use. In this case, specifying `FloatingActionButton`'s behavior will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. The FAB is hidden when the toolbar is collapsed, but it never appear again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@DefaultBehavior` annotation in order to specify the behavior class:

```
@DefaultBehavior(FloatingActionButton.Behavior.class)
public class YourFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton {
  //Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. The FAB is hidden when the toolbar is collapsed. But it never appear again. I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In my custom FAB, I created a method hide. This method was removing the anchorId from the layoutParams. I didn't realize that I was overriding the super class method. What a fool.